# Django: "auto_now_add=True" giving incorrect time

Tags: django, timezone

I would like the current time to be recorded automatically when a record is created in my Django database.

In my model I am using:

```
dateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

From my understanding this automatically stamps the time considering the correct time zone.
Instead however, this is outputting a time that is 5 hours ahead of my local time.

So to try and debug this, I ran this function in my view and printed the output:

```
from django.utils import timezone
timeNow =  timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

timeNow will output the correct time.

So I changed my model to:

```
def get_time():
    return timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

dateTime = models.DateTimeField(default = get_time)
```

This still results in the same incorrect time stamp.

I also changed the timezone in my settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Canada/Central'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Datetime is converted from connection's time zone to UTC on storage and then back to connection's time zone on retrieval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> From my understanding this automatically stamps the time considering the correct time zone.

That's a misunderstanding. See the first sentence of the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/):

> When support for time zones is enabled, **Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database**, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

As you've seen, that UTC datetime can then be converted to whatever you want for display, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**in the models import datetime

in settings.py change the USE_TZ to False**

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

Answer (score -1):

In settings.py file

Keep USE_TZ value to False

USE_TZ = False

This worked for me.

Comment: Don't do this. See the first item here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#faq. To summarise: Q: I don’t need multiple time zones. Should I enable time zone support? A: Yes. When time zone support is enabled, Django uses a more accurate model of local time. This shields you from subtle and unreproducible bugs around Daylight Saving Time (DST) transitions.